# Deploy API which calculates matrix operations

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Is it possible to deploy to cloud a matrix entry form and when 
submit button would be clicked and then an operation using entered matrix as argument would be executed?
So far I am able to deploy `APIFunction[]` and `FormFunction[]` to cloud:

```
    CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"x" -> "Number"}, #x^2 &], Permissions -> "Public"]
    CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"name" -> "String", "age" -> "Integer"}, 1]]
```

, but is there a way I could get similar results to `FormFunction[]`, but instead of form, have a matrix input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by matrix input you mean a grid of input cells, then I believe you have to make it yourself. Here's an example.

```
(* Create a list of field names *)
fields = Flatten@Outer[
    "x" <> ToString@# <> ToString@#2 -> "Number" &,
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {1, 2, 3}
    ];
fieldNames = First /@ fields;

(* Take a FormObject and create a grid of with the inputs *)
layout[form_] := Grid@Map[form[#, "Control"] &, Partition[fieldNames, 3], {2}]

(* Output function *)
dispMatrix[names_][assoc_] := MatrixForm@Partition[assoc /@ names, 3]

(* Deploy it! *)
CloudDeploy@FormFunction[
  fields,
  dispMatrix[fieldNames],
  "PNG",
  FormLayoutFunction -> layout
  ]
```

How it looks:

[image: form example]

Comment: Oh my God, that is incredibly useful. Thank you!

Comment: Pickett, If I want to do some calculations over the form fields. How to access those?

Comment: @Vijay You implement your own `dispMatrix` function that generates whatever result you want to return.